# What Windows function writes a rectangle of pixels?

Tags: c++, windows, pixel

I have been using the [WriteConsoleOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput) function, what it does is write a rectangle of characters to a Command Prompt. However, for making programs that use pixel manipulation rather than character manipulation, what is the Windows function to write a rectangle of pixels? Similar in functionality to WriteConsoleOutput, taking information from an array and writing it, but with pixels instead of characters. I do not mean a line or filled shape as seen in image editors. I mean as in an image stored in an array, and a rectangular chunk of it is written into the screen.

Comment: " I do not mean a line or filled shape as seen in image editors. I mean as in an image stored in an array, and a rectangular chunk of it is written into the screen." The operation of copying a rectangular portion of an image into some same-sized region of a buffer is called *blitting*, which should help you with your web searching.

Comment: I think you are looking for [BitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) but be prepared for a steep learning curve.

Comment: Welcome to the world of GUI programming. Unfortunately, while console programming is rather simple and straight-forward, GUI programming is not. Every modern widget set (and/or framework) I know has the concept of event-based programming: You have a central loop which queues events (e.g. for mouse/kbd input) and calls registered event handlers. The Win-API is no exception. However, you should find doc. and tutorials for this. Btw. I personally prefer Qt for this which is Open Source, portable, well-documented, and IMHO easier to understand than the Win32 API (which is btw. not that modern).

Comment: To detect input I have always done frame-based programming where every 1÷60 of a second I respond to every possible input. Not sure how the display method relates to input though. During a frame it is possible to update the character grid, so it should equally be possible to update the pixel grid.

Comment: The way I already respond to keyboard input is with [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) every frame, the events of pressing and autorepeat built into the program if necessary. So to use mouse input I should similarly be able to use mouse position and make it relative to the window content, and the mouse buttons are already in GetAsyncKeyState.

Comment: Why would I want to write an image file? It would be impractical to have file input output occur every single time the screen graphically updates.

Comment: For instance, in a text editor I have in development, the screen updates every time a character is typed, removed, the text cursor moved and/or selection changed. When porting it from character pseudopixel font thing to proper pixel drawing, I should not be expecting to have every single screen update be an image saving operation, because that would be a lot of them.

Comment: The comment that suggested writing to an image file seems to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The code to graphics is done like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

    const int width = 640;
    const int height = 480;

uint32_t bitmapdata[width*height];

BITMAP bitmap = {0, width, height, width*4, 1, 32, bitmapdata};

BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapinfoheader = {sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), width, -height, 1, 32, BI_RGB, width*height*4, 3779, 3779, 0, 0};

BITMAPINFO bitmapinfo = {bitmapinfoheader, 0};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int main(){
    // Register the window class.
    const char CLASS_NAME[]  = "test2";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = GetModuleHandle( 0 );
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        "test",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window
        NULL,       // Menu
        GetModuleHandle( 0 ),  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);


    MSG msg = { };

    HDC screenhandle = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC handle = GetDC(hwnd);
    HDC screen = CreateCompatibleDC(handle);
    HBITMAP bitmaphandle = CreateCompatibleBitmap(handle, width, height);
    SelectObject(screen, bitmaphandle);

    for(int i=0; i<width*height; i++){
        bitmapdata[i] = i;
    }

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    SetDIBits(screen, bitmaphandle, 0, height, bitmapdata, &bitmapinfo, 0);
    BitBlt(handle, 0, 0, width, height, screen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    }
    return 0;

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_PAINT:
    return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

It does write a rectangle of pixels from an array of pixels, specifically bitmapdata which consists of 32-bit pixel values. The while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){TranslateMessage(&msg);DispatchMessage(&msg);} loop consists of the code to be run every frame, and WindowProc specifies what is executed during the event in DispatchMessage. This example code writes a test rectangle of 640×480 with the pixels being respectively numbered colors.